# SupportMapFragment class creating object of it

Tags: java, android, class

This is my problem. if anyone can help me in this i hugely appreciate it.

```
SupportMapFragment mapFrag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
```

To create a object of a class we have to instantiate it.  So according to this code it should be

```
SupportMapFragment mapFrag = new SupportMapFragment();
```

Then we have to call

```
mapFrag.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
```

I may be wrong. but i want to know how does this code work without new key word.

Comment: @user2509848 You're aware that Java and JavaScript are different languages, right?

Comment: Because that class that you instantiated has a method `getFragmentManager()` which you called on the instance.

Comment: @PM 77-1 Yes, I guess my brain didn't register that.  Sorry about that, I deleted my comment.

Comment: I beleive this is realated to SupportMapFragment class. So i changed the titile of it. Thanks all who helped me in this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you see there is an instance of the [Factory method pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-method-pattern.html);
[image: Factory method pattern]

A factory method lets the API be smarter about exactly how our class can obtain "Product"(s) (or Fragments) as the case may be. It may be as simple as,

```
SupportMapFragment getFragmentManager() {
  return new SupportMapFragment();
}
```

But, I think it more likely, that it's the factory used in a [Flyweight](http://www.oodesign.com/flyweight-pattern.html) implementation (based on the word "Fragment") -

[image: Flyweight pattern]

Comment: It was my thought as well.

Comment: Flyweight?  No, I don't think so.  This is overkill, a stretch given the dearth of information in the original post.

Answer (score 4):

The `SupportMapFragment` is being instantiated inside the `getFragmentManager()` method and the reference returned to you.

Must look something like this:

```
SupportMapFragment getFragmentManager() {
    return new SupportMapFragment();
}
```